# Animation is happening in reverse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, reverse

I'm making a simple animation where when a button is tapped it will change from current position to a certain point. But what's happening is the opposite: it goes from the destination point to the original position. Here's my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.2
          initialSpringVelocity:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         CGFloat amount = 100;
                         self.checkButton.frame = CGRectOffset(self.checkButton.frame, amount, 0);                             
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
```

Comment: Check frame of your button before if condition. May be your if condition will be getting false everytime.

Comment: Have you tried taking out UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState?

Comment: I've removed the if statement altogether to test, same problem. Also, removing UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState doesn't do anything. checkButton was added via Storyboard with constraints, if that helps.

Comment: the code above responded like how you wanted in my case. problem may be in other part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an outlet to the constraint that determine the horizontal position of the checkButton. e.g."hPos".

```
- (IBAction)tapHandler:(id)sender {
        self.hPos.constant = self.hPos.constant + 100;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.0
             usingSpringWithDamping:0.2
              initialSpringVelocity:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{ [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; }
                            completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Instead of search for constraint by identifier, it is much easier to connect the constraint using an outlet.